# How do I delete the intersection of sets A and B from A without sorting in MATLAB?

Tags: sorting, matlab, set-difference

Two matrices, A and B:

```
A = [1 2 3
     9 7 5
     4 9 4
     1 4 7]

B = [1 2 3
     1 4 7]
```

All rows of matrix B are members of matrix A. I wish to delete the common rows of A and B from A without sorting.

I have tried setdiff() but this sorts the output.

For my particular problem (atomic coordinates in protein structures) maintaining the ordered integrity of the rows is important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html):

```
%# find rows in A that are also in B
commonRows = ismember(A,B,'rows');

%# remove those rows
A(commonRows,:) = [];
```

Comment: I LOVE `ismember`! I find uses for it everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

I had to create diff between two arrays without sorting data. I found this great option in matlab docs. [Setdiff function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)

Here is definition of function `[C,ia] = setdiff(___,setOrder)`
If you do not want output data sorted use 'stable' otherwise 'sorted' or without parameter.

Here was my use case.

```
yDataSent = setdiff(ScopeDataY, yDataBefore, 'stable')
yDataBefore = ScopeDataY;
```

Comment: Thanks for your easy solution